# Fixed header and window resize

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I have a fixed header with navigation menu on the site:

```
#header_wrapper
{
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #FD735B;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#header_wrapper .control_wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
#header_wrapper .control_wrapper .control
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.inner_content
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 85%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the HTML of the header:

```
<div id="header_wrapper">
<div class="inner_content">
    <div class="control_wrapper">
        <div class="control local">
            <a class="white_font" id="link_user_experience">USER EXPERIENCE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="control local">
            <a class="white_font" id="link_restocking">RESTOCKING EXPERIENCE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="control local">
            <a class="white_font" id="link_analytics">ANALYTICS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <a class="white_font" id="link_team" href="team">TEAM</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when you resize window and make it narrow part on navigation menu is cut off. And if you trying to scroll horizontally it remains cut off.

Here is an image of the cut off header:

[image: cut off header]

I'm trying to scroll to the right side - the content is scrolled, but the header remains the same:

[image]

How I can make the header look good after resizing?

UPDATE:

I tried to recreate my problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KoulSlou/M3a2y/2/). I set big width to page and header in order to imitate narrow window (my problem appears only when user resize window and make it narrow).

I put 3 titles in header. When you load fiddle you will see only 2 of them. The third one is out of viewable area. I thought that you should just scroll horizontally and fixed header will scroll with the rest of the page. But fixed header is not scrolled and you can not see title #3.

In other words, I need fixed header to scroll horizontally like any other element.

Comment: can you provide a codepen or jsfiddle to better see the issue?

Comment: @jonathan added jsfiddle example.I hope it demonstrate my problem with scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your navigation content is position:absolute; right:0px; which would cause your navigation to go as far right as possible even when the browser is resized.

If you create a li and float:right, display:inline-block it should give you the functionality that you're looking for.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


nav{width:100%;position:absolute;background-color:red;}
nav li{float:right;display:inline-block; padding-right:10px;}
```

Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gBYZ4/3/

*edit: cleaned up my html and fiddle. Had the header floated right by accident.*

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think that my problem is that I can not scroll fixed header horizontally. I added jsfiddle example, which demonstrate my problem.

Comment: Yes, that would be the problem! When something is fixed, you're usually unable to scroll past it because it is "fixed" in the browser.

You could update the header to be "relative" to whatever container it is placed in. Which should allow scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/M3a2y/5/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the solution I wrote on [Fixed top bar that scrolls horizontally with the rest of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19789135/1774680) which seems to be also what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a AJAX Control which helps to overcome this problem. You can use "AlwaysVisibleControlExtender". I have used it in my page and it works perfectly fine.

The below is the asp code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.header{width:100%;height:100px;position:fixed;z-index:1000;}
.content{padding-top:160px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="AlwaysVisibleControlExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkHome" HorizontalOffset="70" VerticalOffset="60" HorizontalSide="Right" VerticalSide="Top">
</ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="AlwaysVisibleControlExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkLogout" HorizontalOffset="20" VerticalOffset="60" HorizontalSide="Right" VerticalSide="Top">
</ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="AlwaysVisibleControlExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblName" HorizontalOffset="110" VerticalOffset="60" HorizontalSide="Right" VerticalSide="Top">
</ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="AlwaysVisibleControlExtender5" runat="server" TargetControlID="Image1" HorizontalSide="Center" VerticalSide="Top">
</ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="150px" ImageUrl="~/Image/ABC.jpg" Width="1594px" />
<p style="margin-left: 1240px; width: 187px;">
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="White"> 
</asp:Label>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkHome" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" Font-Names="Arial">Home</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogout" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" Font-Names="Arial">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
</p>
```

You need to drag and drop Alwaysvisible extender control and give the target control id as above. Hope this helps.