# Fixed top bar that scrolls horizontally with the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to implement a fixed top bar but at the same time it needs to scroll horizontally with the rest of the page; it's not a responsive site

With CSS alone, position: fixed will not scroll with the rest of the page. So there are 2 approaches

1) don't use position fixed and instead leave the container in the document flow but use javascript to position it vertically at the top of the window. The problem with this is the script is not fast enough on the browser and there is a momentary flash of the content just before the top bar moves to cover it each time you scroll vertically.

2) keep position fixed and use javascript to position it horizontally based on the amount of left/right scroll the user is at. The problem with this is mobile phones have an animation on scroll (a sort of acceleration animation) and the script only runs after the animation stops which is also awkward.

So these are the 2 ways I have seen this implemented, I was hoping if you guys had any other options that would work great on small screen desktops and mobile phones Sorry there is no code to highlight because it would take up too much space.

Comment: If you could post a link to your page, i could suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: The problem with using "fixed" positioning is that it takes the element out of flow. thus it can't be re-positioned relative to its parent because it's as if it didn't have one.

You need to use JS. I think the solutions you provided are the only ones.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, looks like you want something like this, the vertical scrollbar is on the far right, but you didn't say anything about that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>scroll</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #topbar
            {
                position: absolute;
                width: 2000px;
                height: 40px;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                border: 1px dashed red;
            }

            #content
            {
                position: absolute;
                width: 2000px;
                left: 0;
                top: 41px;
                bottom: 0;
                border: 1px dotted blue;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topbar">
            Hello topbar
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function(){
                    var n = 1000;
                    do
                    {
                        document.write("<p>some content</p>");
                    } while ( --n );
                })();
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```